# How can I set data from input type that looped by map method to local storage with its ID?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm creating a store website project and creating a cart system with JavaScript.

It can record data of chosen goods that have an id and quantity (through input type), but I can't set the id and quantity to local storage together. I could set only id to local storage.

```
//This is some part of the map method looping code to generate shop.

<div class="buttons">
  <input type="number" placeholder="0" id=${id} class="quantity">
  <button onclick="totalPrice(${id})"><i class="bi bi-cart-plus-fill"></i></button>
</div>
```

```
// Set id and quantity to storage.

let totalPrice = (id) => {
    let selectedItem = id;
    let search = basket.find((x)=> x.id === selectedItem.id);
    if (search === undefined) {
        basket.push({
            id: selectedItem.id
        });
    } else {
        return;
    }
    localStorage.setItem("shopdata", JSON.stringify(basket));
};
```

I want to know how to fix my code to could set id and quantity to local storage I try these code below but the data that show in local storage is `{{}}`.

```
<div class="buttons">
  <input type="number" placeholder="0" id=${id} class="quantity">
  <button onclick="totalPrice(document.getElementById('${id}').value"><i class="bi bi-cart-plus-fill"></i></button>
</div>
```

```
let countGoods = (cardNumb) => {
    let value = parseInt(cardNumb) + 0;
    return value + "ea";
};

let totalPrice = (value) => {
    let selectedItem = value;
    let search = basket.find((x)=> x.value === selectedItem.value);
    if (search === undefined) {
        basket.push({
            quantity: selectedItem.value
        });
    } else {
        search.quantity = selectedItem.value
    }
    localStorage.setItem("shopdata", JSON.stringify(basket));
};
```

Comment: `selectedItem` is the ID, not an object. What is `selectedItem.id` supposed to be?

Comment: What is the value of `id` in the loop that creates the HTML? If it's a string, you need quotes around it: `onclick="totalPrice('${id}')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.getElementById(id)` to get the `<input>` element that contains the quantity.

```js
let totalPrice = (id) => {
  let search = basket.find((x) => x.id === id);
  if (search === undefined) {
    let quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
    if (quantity) {
      basket.push({
        id: id,
        quantity: quantity
      });
      localStorage.setItem("shopdata", JSON.stringify(basket));

    }
  }
};
```